Zellij: activate Python virtualenv on startup
In Zellij I want to activate Python virtualenv on startup with predifined layout.
Some suggested to use direnv shell extension.
But I don`t want to use shell extensions, since layout is intended to be used for collaborative work and I would like to avoid having extra dependencies.
Maybe there is some workaround to make Zellij source venv/bin/activate?
Tried to define layout like this:
layout {
      pane command="bash" {
          args "-c" "source venv/bin/activate"
      }
   }

But this one won`t activate venv.

bash -c "source venv/bin/activate" executes the command and then exit. Try bash -c "source venv/bin/activate"; exec bash that is execute interactive bash in the context of already activated venv.

@phd Thx, should've read bash man page first. But I've managed it work with this
bash -c "bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc; echo 'source venv/bin/activate';)"
And I don't understand why it works, since I'am starting bash shell from bash shell and then closing this outer bash shell. My understanding is that both shells should be closed. But somehow it works.

The following layout.kdl does the trick:
layout {
    pane command="bash" {
        args "-c" "bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc; echo 'source venv/bin/activate';)"
    }
}

I'm still not sure exactly as to why it works as though starting bash with bash -c should`ve resulted in both bash shells to be closed. But it works.
